# How to display the error message beside the field

Tags: php

I am building this simple form where users can input the data but when there is some error for eg invalid email etc.The error which says invalid email appear on the top of the page, I want it to appear on the side of the input fields,I have tried various way but failed, I am a new to programming,Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>login form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
            <label>Name :</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
            <br><br>
            <label>Adress :</label>
            <input type="text" name="adress" id="adress" placeholder="Adress"><br><br>
            <label>E-mail :</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
            <br><br>
            <label>Password :</label>
            <input type="Password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
            <label>Gender :</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" class="radio1">male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" class="radio1">female
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" class="radio1">other
            <br><br>
            <button type="sumbit" value="sumbit" name="sumbit">sumbit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my php code:

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

//define variables and set to empty values
$name = $adress = $email = $password = $gender = "";
$nameErr = $emailErr = "";

if(isset($_POST['sumbit'])){
    if (empty($_POST["name"])){
        $error[] = "Name is required";
    }else{
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
        $error[] = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

    if(empty($_POST["adress"])){
        $error[] = "Adress is required";
    }else{
        $adress = $_POST["adress"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["email"])){
        $error[] = "Email is required";
    }else{
        $email = $_POST["email"];
         // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error[] = "Invalid email format";
    }
}
    if(empty($_POST["password"])){
        $error[] = "Password is required";
    }else{
        $password = $_POST["password"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["gender"])){
        $error[] = "Gender is required";
    }else{
        $gender = $_POST["gender"];
    }
} 

if(empty($error)){
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(name,adress,email,password,gender)VALUES(:name,:adress,:email,:password,:gender)";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(":name",$name);
$statement->bindParam(":adress",$adress);
$statement->bindParam(":email",$email);
$statement->bindParam(":password",$password);
$statement->bindParam(":gender",$gender);
$statement->execute();
}else{
    foreach ($error as $key => $value) {
        echo '<li>'.$value.'<li>';
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: put and id to you form and parse the error mse using that id to the form

Answer (score 0):

**Given that your PHP and HTML code are within the same `.php` file which I guess it is since you are submitting the form to `PHP_SELF`,**

In your HTML code, you can add in a PHP loop to display the errors in your PHP code `$error[]` variable.

For example:

in html file where you want to display the errors:

```
...
    <?php 
    foreach($error as $err){
        echo "<div class='error'>".$err."</div>"; // changed to div to seperate lines
    }
    ?>
...
```

Your current HTML uses the PHP variables `$emailErr` and `$nameErr` which do not get set within your PHP file which is why they may not be appearing after you submit the form.

```
if(empty($_POST["email"])) 
    $emailErr = "Please enter an email.";

if(empty($_POST["name"])) 
    $nameErr = "Name is required.";
```

Comment: You should have a proper CSS for this. Kindly explain it as OP is very *NEW* to programming

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery validation engine for this purpose. It will do your work automatically.

**How to use this?**
Download jquery validation engine plugin from [here.](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) And extract it.

Inside the folder, you can find these two files.

```
jquery.validationEngine-en.js 
jquery.validationEngine.js
```

Copy & Paste in assets->scripts-> of your working project.

Then change the `src` path like below.

```
<script src="assets/scripts/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="assets/scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

For more details you can visit [here](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine)

Comment: Why downvote? please explain... I am open to delete this answer or made changes if required

Comment: He is new to programming and is making a simple PHP script, tossing Javascript libraries at him when he probably does not know Javascript doesn't help him find an answer to the problem.

Comment: @zatyh ***NEW*** doesn't mean that he can't learn it. I have shared a jquery library with proper documentation which is a better solution. It's upto OP what it decides

Comment: It's a simple PHP script and he's learning the basics of backend form validation which is very important, especially with REST APIs and such. Frontend validation alone is not enough ( especially not JQuery ). Even if a library, better to provide VueJS or vanilla javascript as he would likely dive into Laravel

Comment: It doesn't matter. OP can do backend validation without showing error messages. OP asked for the error messages to show along with the text fields which this jquery library does automatically

Comment: Plus this solution is valid for future users as well